# Performing fulltext search with wildcards and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Trying to use MySQL's MATCH AGAINST full text search where my search term is provided by jQueryUIs autocomplete widget as `$_GET['term']`.  Furthermore, I wish to escape the term using PHP's PDO.  Lastly, I would like to use wildcards, however, if it is too much to use wildcards on every word in the provided term, I am okay with just applying it to the last word in the term.  My attempt is below, and the applicable table schema follows.  Problem is it doesn't return any records when only a partial word is supplied in term.  Any suggestions?  Thank you

```
public function searchHelp()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->dontCache();
    try
    {
        $sql ='SELECT id,name AS value FROM topics WHERE MATCH(keywords,name,content) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)';
        $stmt = dbHelp::db()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($_GET['term'].'*'));
        echo(json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){library::sql_error($e,$sql);}   
}

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topics_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `list_order` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `keywords` text,
  `display_list` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_topics_topics` (`topics_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`keywords`,`name`,`content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: why do you thing it's PDO related at all?

Comment: @YourCommonSense.  Don't know if is related.

Comment: @YourCommonSense.  All I know for sure is wildcards are not working.  For instance, searching "stack" returns no results, but "stackoverflow" does. I originally thought PDO might be part of the culprit, but now expect it wasn't.